# How to configure awesome_select 5.2.0 to filter

Tags: flutter

I am trying as follows:

```
  SmartSelect<String>.single(
                  modalFilter: true,
                  title: 'Product Type',
                  choiceItems: options,
                  onChange: (state) => setState(() => value = state.value!),
                  selectedValue: '',
                ),
```

but when I type to filter it doesn't narrow down the list according to my typed value. What's missing?

Answer (score 1):

I just enable `modalFilterAuto: true,` here is the full code:

```
SmartSelect<String>.single(
              modalFilter: true,
              modalFilterAuto: true,
              title: 'Product Type',
              choiceItems: options,
              onChange: (state) => setState(() => value = state.value!),
              selectedValue: '',
            )
```